# ExcelVBA: trying to create userform that searches and reads data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a userform that can search for data and read it into itself. For the record, I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QU9g7N_PgIA). The way my form works is that you have to type in an ID number so it knows what data you want (kinda like Vlookup in a sense). The problem is that no data is retrieved when I hit the command button! Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

row_number = 0
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
item_in_review = Sheets.("Ark1").Cells(row_number, "A")
    If item_in_review = TextBox1.Text Then
       TextBox2.Text = Sheets("Ark1").Cells(row_number, "B")
       TextBox3.Text = Sheets("Ark1").Cells(row_number, "C")
    End If
Loop Until item_in_review = ""

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: we did help you. Now it's your turn to show promised _appreciation_ and give some feedback. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i usually do. Try loading all (or just the first) result into an array. Than just use that row number to retrive all the other information.

```
rowsArray(i) = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Find _
                (What:=productsArray(i), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

First off

`Sheets.("Ark1").Cells(row_number, "A")`

must be

`Sheets("Ark1").Cells(row_number, "A")`

Then I think you must first check for any valid value in `TextBox1.Text`

like follows:

```
Option Explcit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim row_number As Long

    With Me
        If .TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox "please input valid text in 'TextBox1'", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Do
            DoEvents '<-- what's this for?
            row_number = row_number + 1
            item_in_review = Sheets("Ark1").Cells(row_number, "A")
            If item_in_review = .TextBox1.Text Then
               .TextBox2.Text = Sheets("Ark1").Cells(row_number, "B")
               .TextBox3.Text = Sheets("Ark1").Cells(row_number, "C")
               Exit Sub '<--| if you want the first match to fill TextBox2 and TextBox3
            End If
        Loop Until item_in_review = ""
    End With
End Sub
```